# Typecasting a negative number to positive in C

Tags: c

I wouldn't expect the value that gets printed to be the initial negative value.  Is there something I'm missing for type casting?

```
#include<stdint.h>


int main() {

    int32_t color = -2451337;
    uint32_t color2 = (uint32_t)color;

    printf("%d", (uint32_t)color2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not? You're asking printf to print a *signed decimal number* with `%d`.

Comment: Ok I see.  I had to use %u for unsigned.  I figured typecasting would convert the number though?

Comment: Sure, typecasting changes how the bits are interpreted. However, what you pass to printf is untyped and printf relies on the format string to figure out what the bits mean.

Comment: You don't need the casts.

Comment: Well, I do need the casting.  The printing was really for testing but I'm trying to figure it out casting in general.  I just didn't think I needed to worry about d / u for printing too.  I figured the casting would have converted it.

Comment: What if I wanted the number to be the positive value when it gets to printf - there isn't a way to do that?

Comment: I think the confusion comes from object-oriented languages where variables are responsible for displaying themselves.  In the C language, a variable is just a bunch of bits.  How those bits get displayed as a number depends entirely on the format string that you pass to `printf`, it does not depend on the variable type.  Having mismatch between the format specifier and the actual variable type is considered a programming error, and will generate a warning on some compilers.

Comment: Ok thank you.  That makes sense.  And yes, I'm used to Java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int32_t color = -2451337;
uint32_t color2 = (uint32_t)color;
```

The cast is unnecessary; if you omit it, exactly the same conversion will be done implicitly.

For any conversion between two numeric types, if the value is representable in both types, the conversion preserves the value. But since `color` is negative, that's not the case here.

For conversion from a signed integer type to an unsigned integer type, the result is *implementation-defined* (or it can raise an implementation-defined signal, but I don't know of any compiler that does that).

Under *most* compilers, conversions between integer types of the same size just copies or reinterprets the bits making up the representation. The standard requires `int32_t` to use two's-complement representation, so *if* the conversion just copies the bits, then the result will be `4292515959`.

(Other results are permitted by the C standard, but not likely to be implemented by real-world compilers. The standard permits one's-complement and sign-and magnitude representations for signed integer types, but specifically requires `int32_t` to use two's-complement; a C compiler for a one's complement CPU probably just would't define `int32_t`.)

```
printf("%d", (uint32_t)color2);
```

Again, the cast is unnecessary, since `color2` is already of type `uint32_t`. But the `"%d"` format requires an argument of type `int`, which is a signed type (that may be as narrow as 16 bits). In this case, the `uint32_t` value isn't *converted* to `int`. Most likely the representation of `color2` will be treated *as if* it were an `int` object, but the behavior is undefined, so as far as the C standard is concerned quite literally anything could happen.

To print a `uint32_t` value, you can use the `PRId32` macro defined in `<inttypes.h>`:

```
printf("%" PRId32, color32);
```

Or, perhaps more simply, you can convert it to the widest unsigned integer type and use `"%ju"`:

```
printf("%ju", (uintmax_t)color32);
```

This will print the implementation-defined value (probably `4292515959`) of `color32`.

And you should add a newline `\n` to the format string.

More quibbles:

You're missing `#include <stdio.h>`, which is required if you call `printf`.

`int main()` is ok, but `int main(void)` is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

You took a bunch of bits (stored in signed value). You then told the CPU to interpret that bunch of bits as unsigned. You then told the cpu to render the same bunch of bits as signed again (%d). You would therefore see the same as you first entered.

C just deals in bunches of bits. If the value you had chosen was near the representational limit of the type(s) involved (read up on twos-complement representation), then we might see some funky effects, but the value you happened to choose wasn't. So you got back what you put in.